# syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Tags: php

I think I've been staring at this for too long that now I'm failing to identify the problem.

Can someone kindly point out where this is going wrong?

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mipbi/includes/classes/html.php on line 11
```

Code:

```
public static function textbox($name, $maxlength=''){
    return "<input type='text' id='$name' name='$name'  maxlength='$maxlength' value='". if (isset($_POST[$name])) { echo $name; } ."' >";
}
```

The error is generated at the if statement line.

Comment: what's the if doing concatenated to a return followed by an echo?

Comment: Its so bad I can't even spell right, lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use if statements like that.

To do what you want to achieve you'll need to do this:

```
public static function textbox($name, $maxlength=''){
    return "<input type='text' id='$name' name='$name'  maxlength='$maxlength' value='".(isset($_POST[$name]) ? $name : '')."' >";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use if statements in such a way. Use the ternary operator for that purpose or have your variable pre-made before the concatenation.

```
public static function textbox($name, $maxlength=''){
    return "<input type='text' id='$name' name='$name'  
    maxlength='$maxlength' value='". (isset($_POST[$name]) ? $name : '')."' >";
}
```

Alternative:

```
public static function textbox($name, $maxlength='')
{
    if( !isset($_POST[$name] ) {
        $myname = $name;
    } else {
        $myname = '';
    }

return "<input type='text' id='$name' name='$name'  
maxlength='$maxlength' value='". $myname ."' >";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try it this way:

```
public static function textbox($name, $maxlength=''){
    return "<input type='text' id='".$name."' name='".$name."'  maxlength='".$maxlength."' value='".( (isset($_POST[$name]) ? $name:'')."' >";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the if function inside the retuned value string. I would build the string you want to return first, then return it. In my example the string to be returned is `$out`. Even if the above worked this is easier to read and maintain.

```
$out= "<input type='text' id='$name' name='$name'  maxlength='$maxlength' value='";
if (isset($_POST[$name])) {
    $out.= $name; 
} 
$out .='" >";
return $out;
```

Comment: Can you expand on why/how your proposed solution solves the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function textbox($name, $maxlength=''){
    return "<input type='text' id='$name' name='$name'  maxlength='$maxlength' value='". if (isset($_POST[$name])) { echo $name; } ."' >";
}
```

should be:

```
public static function textbox($name, $maxlength=''){
    $ret = "<input type='text' id='$name' name='$name'  maxlength='$maxlength' value='";
    if (isset($_POST[$name])) { $ret .= $name; }
    return $ret . "' >";
}
```